# how to list all users of a specific role on a page?

Tags: wordpress

Is there any plugin for listing all the users of a specific role on a wordpress page.

I have searched for it but did not find any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a plugin for this so you might have to do this in php.

Check out this forum here

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/display-info-of-user-with-certain-role-or-level-ini-wp-27 specifically the last post with code in it by Jim de Groot.

He is doing the same thing as you want to it looks like.

If your confused by the code let me know and I can run you through it

Comment: they are displaying the list of users but I want to link every users to its profile page.

Comment: He does in this line --- echo "<a href='.$user_link.' title='.$curuser->display_name.'>";  It may not work the same for you but you could just change the href to go to the users page by their user ID.

Answer (score 2):

My answer sort of launches off of @daz-reid 's answer. Notice that I'm filtering for a custom role called "member". This code works as of 4.2.3, on a GoDaddy shared WordPress Managed Hosting (mentioned because of the use of the server variable):

```
//Load WP API as its an external page
require_once( $_SERVER['CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/' . 'wp-load.php' );

// Now have access to get_users
$membersArray = get_users( 'role=member' );

/*
These are the properties you can output:
[ID] => 4
[user_login] => josemborge
[user_pass] => $P$BIBdietTgVJlKqHuFGuOXWg5tWo56w.
[user_nicename] => josemeborge
[user_email] => joborge@somemail.com
[user_url] => 
[user_registered] => 2017-10-12 14:44:01
[user_activation_key] => 1507819441:$P$B7Hq4KOzrneDM1Bb0m.R94bQXFZKdj1
[user_status] => 0
[display_name] => Jose Borge
*/

//Now, to loop through the $membersArray and output each display_name:
foreach($membersArray as $member){
   echo $member->data->display_name . "<br>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer for your question has been well explained on this link http://wpengineer.com/365/list-all-users-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar problem that involved doing the same but on a page external to wordpress. If it helps, here is what i did.

```
<?php 
    //Load WP API as its an external page 
    require 'blog/wp-load.php';

    // Now have access to get_users
    $membersArray = get_users( 'role=role-goes-here' );

    // Array of WP_User objects.
    foreach ( $bandMembers as $bandMember ){
      echo esc_html( $bandMember->nickname  )
    } 


?>
```

Hope it helps matey.

Comment: I'm going to add my modified answer, which is based on your answer, but perhaps with some WP updates certain code has changed. Also, you use `$membersArray`, then for some reason you switch to `$bandMembers` in your `foreach` loop.